# Examples of funny graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

In order to arouse interest of my high school students to plot graphs I want to plot interesting funny graphs such as the one of the [batman equation](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=batman%20equation&oq=batman%20equation&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j35i39j69i61j0.2143j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I'm looking something simpler, maybe in a form of a piece-wise function.

I want to plot it in class.

Comment: Depending on your point of view, you may think that [Tupper's self-referential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) is trivial, or totally awesome. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring It seems really interesting, but I think I won't be able to plot this graph by hand in class

Answer (score 9):

Though it's not funny, but one of very beautiful graphs is "The Love Graph".

> \begin{align}
> &x =16\sin^3 t \\
> &y = 13\cos t -5\cos 2t -2\cos 3t -\cos 4t
> \end{align}

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I won't be able to plot this graph by hand in class

Comment: @user42912 Certainly you won't be able to, let me search for some graphs that are easy to plot by hand. As you mentioned the Batman Equation, I thought you may be using projector or something like that in your class.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you find something easier please let me know

Answer (score 4):

how about
$$\sin(\sin(x))=\cos(\sin(xy)+\cos(x)?$$

Comment: I think you should add the picture

Answer (score 3):

$$y = | \sin(x)| + 5\exp(-x^{100})\cos(x) , -\pi < x < \pi$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I won't be able to plot this graph by hand in class

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{2/3} +y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$$
it graphs as an astroid or a star shaped curve